# Pyramid detecting a photo upload

Tags: python, pyramid

So I have a settings page, and the user can upload a photo to the website with a post request from a form, but right now, I can't detect if the user uploaded a photo or not, since there are also other parts of the form, with one submit button at the bottom. Right now, I'm using `if 'file_input' in request.POST:`, but it always returns true, even though the user didn't upload a photo. How can I detect if the user actually uploaded a photo. The html is:

```
<form class="group-photo" action="/${groupName}/settings" method="post" style="vertical-align:text-bottom" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <span style="font-size:17px;font-weight:bold;">Group Photo</span>
            <img style="border-radius:15px;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" src="/static/group/${photo_id}_120.${photo_ext}">
            <br>
            <div class="fileinputs">
                <input class="file" type="file" name="file_input" value="Choose image">

                <div class="fakefile" style="margin-left:40px;">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Choose image"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <span style="font-size:17px;font-weight:bold;">Description</span>
            <textarea class="groupbio" name="groupbio">${bio}</textarea>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submitted" value="Save Changes"></p>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The browser includes all file input elements in the form, even when empty, so the `'file_input' in request.POST'` test will always be True, but if empty, it's an empty unicode string (`u''`).

A proper file upload has a filename, test for that:

```
if 'file_input' in request.POST and hasattr(request.POST['file_input'], 'filename'):
```

File uploads are `cgi.FieldStorage` instances, and the `filename` test is what the [`cgi` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) recommends:

> If a field represents an uploaded file, accessing the value via the value attribute or the getvalue() method reads the entire file in memory as a string. This may not be what you want. You can test for an uploaded file by testing either the filename attribute or the file attribute.